# Android Image Button fade Images

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

I have one image button and I would like to fade out one image and fade in the other. I don't want the background of the image to fade out(i dont ever want the entire button to be transparent)

The only solution I have found so far is to have two buttons stacked and fade one in while the other fades out. Is there any way that I can do this with just one button??

Ideally I won't have to stack images/image buttons to make this happen. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.... I never figured out a way to do this. I ended up just stacking two imageButtons and fading out one while the other fades in.